# UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication - Unable to unprotect the message.State Error Message

Tags: azure, .net-core, openid-connect, identityserver4, google-openidconnect

I am trying to add Google and Azure Active Directory authorities as OpenIdConnect options in my application.

If i add each of them separately, it works fine.
But if i add them both i get the following error message:

**Unable to unprotect the message.State**

These are the OpenIdConnectOptions configuration:

```
        //Google
        appBuilder.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {                 
            ClientId = ".....apps.googleusercontent.com",
            Authority = $"https://accounts.google.com",
            ClientSecret = "xxxyyyzzzz",
            AuthenticationScheme = "Google",
            DisplayName = "Google",
            AutomaticChallenge = true                                       
        });

        //Azure AD Providers
        var schemeName = "Azure Active Directory";
        var clientId = "1234567890";  
        var tenantId = "0987654321";  

        appBuilder.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {               
            ClientId = clientId,
            ClientSecret = "aaaaabbbbcccc",
            Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}",
            AuthenticationScheme = "Azure Active Directory",
            DisplayName = "Azure Active Directory",
            AutomaticChallenge = true,                                                
        });
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you have multiple OIDC middleware, you need to set a unique `CallbackPath` for each of them. Otherwise they are stepping on each other's toes when handling the callback.

Comment: yes that was the issue. I thought that just the Authentication Scheme needed to be unique.

Comment: I don't have multiple OIDC middleware still facing the issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't have mutilple OIDC middlewares too and still facing the error

Comment: This answer clarifies and includes an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42404177/multiple-identityserver-federation-error-unable-to-unprotect-the-message-state