# Asp.net Core 1.1: AggregateException: Unhandled remote failure. (Unable to unprotect the message.State.)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-1.1

I'm using the custom external URL to login, which authenticate the user and send back the control to calling website with claims.

Application was working fine on stage till yesterday. Now suddenly it start giving an exception which I've no clue about and I also don't know where to check

Raw Exception  details:

```
System.AggregateException: Unhandled remote failure. (Unable to unprotect the message.State.) ---> System.Exception: Unable to unprotect the message.State.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.<HandleRemoteCallbackAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.<HandleRequestAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.<HandleRequestAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Unable to unprotect the message.State.<---
```

Code unchanged in `Configure` before and after this exception is as follows

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies"
            });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
            {
                AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
                SignInScheme = "Cookies",

                Authority = signinAuthority,
                RequireHttpsMetadata = signinHTTPS,

                ClientId = "clientId",
                ClientSecret = "secret",

                ResponseType = "code id_token",
                Scope = { "api1", "offline_access" },

                GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
                SaveTokens = true
            });
```

URL has `/signin-oidc` at the end

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Any changes made in your application or the program using the external URL before it stopped working yesterday?

Comment: same external url  is working fine with the production and dev environments.

this error is occuring on my stage instance only, Stage,production & dev all have the same exact copy deployed

Comment: What is the signinAuthority variable?

Comment: refers to external URL which authenticate the user. Login page is also on that external page. which redirect back to the website with claims 
value of the variable : https://my.website.com.au/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43758879/useopenidconnectauthentication-unable-to-unprotect-the-message-state-error-mes

this url  accepted answer : When you have multiple OIDC middleware, you need to set a unique CallbackPath for each of them. Otherwise they are stepping on each other's toes when handling the callback.

I'm not using any other oidc middleware