# IdentityServer4 N-Multitenant AzureAD - Unable to unprotect message.state

Tags: azure-active-directory, identityserver4, multi-tenant

I am in the process of building out a Saas-based multi-tenant framework.  (e.g. tenant1.mydomain.com, tenant2.mydomain.com). Tenants are database-driven and not 4known during app startup. The Auth server is auth.mydomain.com and is currently running IdentityServer4 & AspNetIdentity.

Tenants have will have the option to bring their own AzureAD provider and will supply their own ClientID and TenantID.

I already have the MVC Client sending over the tenant properties like such

```
        services.AddAuthentication(o =>
        {
            o.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            o.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie("Cookies")
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", o =>
        {
            o.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
            o.Authority = Configuration.GetSection("MicroFlux")["OidcAuthority"];
            o.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
            o.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            o.ClientId = Configuration.GetSection("OidcClientSettings")["ClientId"];
            o.ClientSecret = Configuration.GetSection("OidcClientSettings")["ClientSecret"];
            o.ResponseType = Configuration.GetSection("OidcClientSettings")["ResponseType"];
            //options.SaveTokens = true;
            o.Scope.Add("roles");
            o.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
            {
                SetTenantRedirectToIdentityProps(n);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        });

    public void SetTenantRedirectToIdentityProps(RedirectContext n)
    {

        var tenant = n.HttpContext.GetTenant();

        if (tenant != null && tenant.TenantSsoProviderType != TenantSSOProviderType.MicroFluxIdentity)
        {
            //set props to auth server that reflects tenant's settings

            n.ProtocolMessage.Parameters.Add("tenantid", tenant.Id.ToString());
            n.ProtocolMessage.Parameters.Add("tenantname", tenant.Name);

            switch (tenant.TenantSsoProviderType)
            {
                case TenantSSOProviderType.AzureAd:
                    n.ProtocolMessage.Parameters.Add("preferred_provider", "aad_" + tenant.Name);
                    n.ProtocolMessage.Parameters.Add("aad_authority", $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant.SSO_AzureAd_TenantId}/v2.0");
                    n.ProtocolMessage.Parameters.Add("aad_clientid", tenant.SSO_AzureAd_ClientId);
                    break;
                case TenantSSOProviderType.Okta:
                    n.ProtocolMessage.Parameters.Add("preferred_provider", "okta");
                    //todo:add okta next
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
```

This part works well as the redirect to my identity server (auth.mydomain.com) can access the authority url, client id at runtime (mostly written from this [How can I set the Authority on OpenIdConnect middleware options dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52955238/how-can-i-set-the-authority-on-openidconnect-middleware-options-dynamically)).

My relevant auth startup.cs code has this:

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie("Cookies")
        .AddOpenIdConnect("aad", "Login with Azure AD", o =>
        {
            o.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
            o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {ValidateIssuer = false};
            o.ClientId = "<<set dynamically>>";
            o.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
        });

        services.AddSingleton<TenantProvider>();
        services.AddSingleton<IOptionsMonitor<OpenIdConnectOptions>, OpenIdConnectOptionsProvider>();
        services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>, OpenIdConnectOptionsInitializer>();
```

Here's the tenant provider:

```
public class TenantProvider
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public TenantProvider(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) => _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;

    public bool UsingExternalProvider { get; set; } = false;
    public string Authority { get; set; }
    public string SSO_AzureAd_ClientId { get; set; }
    public string SignInScheme { get; set; }


    public string GetCurrentTenant()
    {
        var name = "default";
        var cntx = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

        if (cntx != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cntx.Request.Query["returnUrl"]))
        {

            var decodedQueryString = WebUtility.UrlDecode(cntx.Request.Query["returnUrl"]);
            var dict = QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(decodedQueryString);

            UsingExternalProvider = true;

            if (dict.ContainsKey("preferred_provider") && dict["preferred_provider"].ToString().StartsWith("aad_"))
            {
                Authority = dict["aad_authority"].ToString();
                SSO_AzureAd_ClientId = dict["aad_clientid"];
                SignInScheme = dict["tenantname"].ToString().ToLower();
            }

            name = dict["tenantname"];

        }

        return name ?? "default";
    }
}

public class OpenIdConnectOptionsInitializer : IConfigureNamedOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>
{
    private readonly IDataProtectionProvider _dataProtectionProvider;
    private readonly TenantProvider _tenantProvider;

    public OpenIdConnectOptionsInitializer(
        IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider,
        TenantProvider tenantProvider)
    {
        _dataProtectionProvider = dataProtectionProvider;
        _tenantProvider = tenantProvider;
    }

    public void Configure(string name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
    {
        if (!string.Equals(name, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            //return;
        }

        var tenant = _tenantProvider.GetCurrentTenant();

        // Create a tenant-specific data protection provider to ensure
        // encrypted states can't be read/decrypted by the other tenants.
        options.DataProtectionProvider = _dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector(tenant);

        // Other tenant-specific options like options.Authority can be registered here.
        options.Authority = _tenantProvider.Authority;
        options.ClientId = _tenantProvider.SSO_AzureAd_ClientId;
        options.SignInScheme = _tenantProvider.SignInScheme;

    }

    public void Configure(OpenIdConnectOptions options)
        => Debug.Fail("This infrastructure method shouldn't be called.");
}
```

Current State: 
Everything above seems to work in that I am able to redirect to the tenant's AzureAD instance, complete a login, and then receive back the ID Token from the dynamically-determined authority.

However, upon arriving back from AzureAD to my /signin-oidc endpoint, I receive the following error:

Exception: Unable to unprotect the message.State.
Unknown location

I have referenced several posts about this (e.g. [Multiple IdentityServer Federation : Error Unable to unprotect the message.State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42404177/multiple-identityserver-federation-error-unable-to-unprotect-the-message-state)) and the accepted resolution was to have unique return urls for different providers. But I am confused as to what to do from here as I have a single provider that I want to modify based on the request to authenticate from the downstream MVC client.

Side question: since I am getting back id_token from the dynamic AzureAD provider, should I just implement my own login logic and manually log in the user and skip the /signin-oidc endpoint all together? There's so much conflicting information out there; hoping I am close.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it in another way which is more simple. You can define your tenants as an [ApiResource](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/stable/reference/api_resource.html) in IdentityServer. when you are redirecting your user for authentication, you should specify your tenant using *scope*.

In IdentityServer you should implement all possible OAuth services like Azure. Then during user authentication, user will select its way.

Comment: Sounds interesting and simpler if I could get it to work. Is there an example you could direct me to for reference? I'm interested in seeing how I can still use a Hybrid flow against an Api Resource so that the user's browser is redirected to AzureAD to complete their sign in, and then return with the Id_token that I can then use to construct the claims principal in my auth.mydomain.com world.

Thanks.

Comment: There is an open source project which does a lot of required operations, but not exactly this scenario. [skoruba](https://github.com/skoruba/IdentityServer4.Admin).