# Caching Issue: ASP.NET Core, failed to get access token

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

GetUserAccessTokenAsync by using this method I am trying to get the Token, The same code working fine in POC App, where as in the real application I am getting **TokenNotFound**.

User is authenticated and able to get the userId too, at the end I am getting **account** as null, it leads to the main error.

```
 public async Task<string> GetUserAccessTokenAsync(string userId)
        {
            var account = await _app.GetAccountAsync(userId);
            if (account == null) throw new ServiceException(new Error
            {
                Code = "TokenNotFound",
                Message = "User not found in token cache. Maybe the server was restarted."
            });

            try
            {
                var result = await _app.AcquireTokenSilent(_scopes, account).ExecuteAsync();
                return result.AccessToken;
            }

            // Unable to retrieve the access token silently.
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new ServiceException(new Error
                {
                    Code = GraphErrorCode.AuthenticationFailure.ToString(),
                    Message = "Caller needs to authenticate. Unable to retrieve the access token silently."
                });
            }
        }
```

**Note**: The same code working fine in POC application, I tried with same app resource and created new app resource too.

Please help me what exactly I am missing...

Answer (score 0):

I have a sample with asp.net core mvc, which integrate MSAL to obtain access token for calling Ms graph api. I don't know what is `POC App` actually, but per my searching, `AcquireTokenSilent` may from MSAL.js

Here's the detail.

Adding configurations in appsetting file about azure ad:

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "your_tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "tenant_id",
    "ClientId": "azure_ad_client_id", 
    "ClientSecret": "client_secret", 
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",//don't forget to set redirect url in azure portal
    "SignedOutCallbackPath ": "/signout-callback-oidc"
}
```

installing packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="1.23.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="1.23.1" />
```

StartUp.cs, don't forget to add `app.UseAuthentication();app.UseAuthorization();` in `Configure` method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration)
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "user.read" })
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

    // Require authentication
    services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    })
    // Add the Microsoft Identity UI pages for signin/out
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
}
```

And my test Controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebAppMvc.Models;

namespace WebAppMvc.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ITokenAcquisition _tokenAcquisition;

        public HomeController(ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition)
        {
            _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
        {
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };
            string accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes);
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

If the redirection url is wrong after signing in, just changing the url in browser manually to `localhost:xxx/home`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, actually I followed your steps and able to generate **token**, but I want add ``` string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };
            string accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes); ``` lines code into else condition on my above method, which helps me to get graph photo stream. But I am getting following error. System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed'. Please suggest. and when mention poc is proof of concept or sample application. My moto to get profile pic

Comment: Could you pls show us your `ConfigureServices` method in your `Startup.cs` file? Your error message means the injection of _tokenAcquisition met issue and you may not inject it.. If your  `ConfigureServices` is the same as mine, then you may check if you inject it in your construct method of your Controller.

Comment: services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>{options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;});  services.AddSingleton<IGraphAuthProvider, GraphAuthProvider>();
services.AddSingleton<IGraphServiceClientFactory, GraphServiceClientFactory>();

Comment: services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration).EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "user.read" })
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});

Comment: I added here above my code from startup.cs; Tiny please help

Comment: Did you inject `_tokenAcquisition` into the construct method of the class that you want to use _tokenAcquisition?
`private readonly ITokenAcquisition _tokenAcquisition;
public HomeController(ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition){_tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;}`

Comment: Yes. I did it. But not in HomeController, that I am using GraphAuthProvider.cs Class. Because I want this should be executed when my actual code jump to else block

Comment: Actual Error: Singleton ImplementationType: XXX.Services.GraphAuthProvider': Cannot consume scoped service 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.ITokenAcquisition' from singleton 'XXX.Services.IGraphAuthProvider'.

Comment: could you pls try to use `services.AddScoped<IGraphAuthProvider, GraphAuthProvider>();` instead of `services.AddSingleton<IGraphAuthProvider, GraphAuthProvider>();` `Cannot consume scoped` means you used `Singleton` here but it required to be `scoped`

Comment: Seems it worked a bit. But now getting this : ( Exception: Unable to unprotect the message.State.
Unknown location

Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler<TOptions>.HandleRequestAsync()

Comment: Could you pls check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42425810)? I'm afraid you need to double confirm the `appsetting.json` file to check the value of `CallbackPath` and if it matched the redirect url you set in azure portal. In azure portal-> azure ad->your app-> authentication, you may set the redirect url like `https://localhost:xxxx/`

Comment: I did setup redirect url and its mached Tiny.  and I am using "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc", this as call back path. above answer also not helped me. really appreciate your patience, to help on this issue.

Comment: Then can [this question](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/1555) help you?

Comment: Main root cause for this issue is var account = await _app.GetAccountAsync(userId); in this line account is getting null. if I get valid data into account it will work. still its not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

At Finally I have followed below link it helped to get rid of my all queries for graph API;

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-aspnet-core